# Problem with document PyCharm project with Sphinx

Tags: python, pycharm, python-sphinx

I want to make documentation of my pycharm project. 
I made in my project directory ("model") a directory docs. I installed sphinx and with use of sphinx-quickstart I made all necessary files. Then I edited "conf.py". I uncommented:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

And I added:

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.doctest',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    'sphinx.ext.coverage',
    'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
    'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.githubpages',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon'
]
```

In project "model" I have 4 files (file1.py, file2.py, file3.py and file4.py) so I edited index.rst like this:

```
File1
=====================================

.. toctree:: model.file1
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:


File2
=====================================

.. toctree:: model.file2
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:


File3
=====================================

.. toctree:: model.file3
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:


File4
=====================================

.. toctree:: model.file4
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:
```

But after "make html" it gives me `error:  WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'model.file1'`

Do you know how to make that documentation? 
How to make pdf file with it?

Comment: From the comments on the answer, it is clear that you have edited your project after it was pointed out that you had misunderstood how `toctree` works. The question does not reflect that.

Comment: OK, you posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58154712/407651.

Answer (score 1):

The [`toctree` directive does not do what you think it does](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree).  Specifically it should be a reStructuredText file, not a Python file.

Instead if you want to document the docstrings in your Python package and its modules, you should read about [`autodoc` and `sphinx-apidoc`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html), and make sure you have an `__init.py__` inside `model` so that it is a Python package.

Finally it is highly unusual to place reStructuredText files inside packages, where best practice is to put only code inside the package and put the documentation stuff outside of it.

Comment: Could you tell me in few steps how to make that document? I have these python files. I made a "docs" directory. I used commend "sphinx-apidoc -o "docs directory" "root files"" and I edited index.rst by writing modules on the end of this but it still does't work.

Comment: ok. I made a progress. Right now I have a error: "WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'agent_random' from module 'model'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'torch'"
... Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I have no insight to `torch` or where it would be in your packages. Wherever it is, it must be importable by Sphinx.